# Вернуть вектор объектов класса из функции

Tags: c++, ооп, vector, шаблоны-с++

Вообще функция огромная и нет смысла кидать её полностью, так как работаю с openGL, но суть такова, что я пытаюсь вернуть вектор и поместить его в конструктор объекта класса Field. Тему шаблонов вроде изучал, но тут немного другое и такого не делал раньше

```
template <class type>
std::vector<type> generationBones()
{
    std::vector<Program::Bone> bones(16); //вектор объектов костей
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < bones.size(); i++) bones[i].num = i + 1;
    return bones;
}
Field field(*generationBones()*); <-отсутствуют экземпляры функции функции...
```

В самом классе я описал конструктор так

```
template <class type>
    Field::Field(std::vector<type> _bones)
    {   
}
```

Тоже самое сделал и в заголовочном

```
template <class type>
        Field(std::vector<type>);
```

Comment: А где вы в `generationBones` вообще используете `type`? Хоть раз? А во-вторых, раз среди аргументов `type` не используется, уго нужно указывать при вызове функции явно - откуда компилятору знать, что вы хотите?

Comment: Тогда вместо std::vector<Program::Bone> bones(16); нужно дописать 
std::vector<type> bones(16); ?

Comment: Нет, `bones<int>(16)`, например :) Почему не `bones<Program::Bone>(16)`? Потому что вы написали **якобы** шаблон, который **по сути** шаблоном не является. Выбросьте это свое `template <class type>
std::vector<type>`, напишите вместо `std::vector<Program::Bone>` и не заморачивайтесь с шаблонами...

Comment: std::vector<Program::Bone> generationBones()
{
        .....
 std::vector<Program::Bone> bones(16); //вектор объектов костей
 for (std::size_t i = 0; i < bones.size(); i++) bones[i].num = i + 1;
        ....
 bones[0](temp_coordinate); //1
 return bones;

}
ругается на bones[0] вызов объекта типа  класса без соответствусющей функции operator() ...

Comment: Я не ясновидящий, а что такое `Bone`, вы не написали. Я ответил на ВАШ вопрос, а не на вытекающий из него следующий (кстати, потом будет - нет конструктора  Filed, принимающего указатель на функцию...) Сами посмотрите, есть оператор () у вашего `Bone` или нет, и если нет - зачем его вызывать?